# Using DijkstraShortestPath from jgrapht throws compile time error

Tags: java, java-8, jgrapht

I am trying to get Dijkstra Shortest Path using jgrapht. The simplified snippet looks like this:

```
SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph<StopNode, WeightedEdge> graph = new SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph<StopNode, WeightedEdge>(WeightedEdge.class);
StopNode startNode = pickStartNodeFromGraph();
StopNode endNode = pickEndNodeFromGraph();
List<StopNode> shortestPath = DijkstraShortestPath.findPathBetween(graph, startNode, endNode);
```

All I get is compile time error in DijkstraShortestPath.findPathBetween method, stating 
that `incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s).`
I know that I am missing something, but it is the middle of the night and I could really use some help here.

Comment: We can't see `pick<Start|End>NodeFromGraph()` - I presume they both return objects of type `StopNode` (not subclasses or anything)?

Comment: I'd guess at the problem being thrown from [this line](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/blob/master/jgrapht-core/src/main/java/org/jgrapht/alg/DijkstraShortestPath.java#L108).  Are all vertices in the graph of type `StopNode`? It looks like the `.equals` on that line is complaining that it is being passed incompatible types, maybe.

Comment: issue is likely in your graph gen or your pick node functions

Comment: As far as I can see (it’s hard from this small code snippet), the return type will be `List<WeightedEdge>` not `List<StopNode>`.

Comment: Yes, it was all about WeightedEdge and it was THAT simple. I got temporally completely darkened. Thank you for help!